# Java.lang.finalize heap get too big during hadoop url parsing job

Tags: java, html, hadoop, garbage-collection

I am attempting to go through a list of urls and analyse the contents of their homepages.  To do this I have a Hadoop mapper with no reducer that gets the urls and sends them to a parser class to parse.

The parser uses [Jericho's html parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/StreamedSource.html)'s streamed source class to read the contents of the page.  It actually takes in the contents of said page with the use of a buffered reader.  I have it call the close method of both the streamed source and the buffered reader class, after which my mapper calls the parsers toString method and continues to the next url.

A quick **memory analysis** showed that there is a heap of finalize objects that the garbage collector cannot seem to keep up with.  I've heard bad things about the reliability of `System.gc()` so I'm wondering if there is another cleaner way to get rid of this giant heap of finalize objects.

Comment: Let it be noted that system.gc() seems to be working well but I'd really like something more reliable, nulling everything did not work very well at all.

Comment: I learned something that very much helped with the issue, when writing a mapper do not create and instantiate objects in the map method if you can help it. Instead make them instance variables in the class otherwise you'll have an unexpected number of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to **remove the finalizers** from your code. The JVM does not guarantee when the finalizing code will be invoked. Other problem, which you are experiencing, is that the finalizer thread may not be able to keep up with the allocation rate of your app.

Analyze the life cycle of the objects that are using the finalizers and identify at which point the finalizing code can be invoked, change the code so that the finalizer is not defined and call all the close/finalizing sequences manually.

Comment: I close the underlying streams manually, it seems to be Jericho thats calling Finalize.  I know exactly where refrences to the object stop (try-catch-finally block.  Is there anything besides System.gc() that I can do to garantee that my steaming source objects get cleaned up?

Comment: Also all the finalize seems to do is call a close() method that I already call myself.

Comment: So could you just removed it and see what happens. Looks like you have the heap dump so there you can see to which class the Finalizers belong to. So then you can modify that specific class by commenting out the `finalize()` method.

Comment: I've found the finalizers that are clogging up everything and I'm nearly positive they are from jericho.  Is there a way that does not involve recompiling that library from source with such a small change that I can do to avoid the finalizers?

Comment: You could try recompiling only that one class containing the finalizer. That should work and you do not need to recompile the whole lib. After that put that compiled class into the classpath in front of the jericho jars.

Comment: I ended up having to add the source to my project which did help solve the memory issues.  Afterwards I found a bigger error that might have prevented the garbage collector from running involving my urlreader object not having a readTimeout.